# How to turn off Magnifying glass ( not the one in accessibility)

Tags: ipad

How do I turn off the circular magnifier in iOS?  I am not referring to the accessibility feature.  For example, when I open a pdf and hold my Apple pencil down somewhere, a circular magnifying glass pops up.  This is not a problem in pdf although it is annoying.  However, I have other apps for which this does interfere with my work.  One of my apps requires me to drag things around with a clear view of what i am dragging.  The magnifier gets in the way of what i am doing.  I would like to turn it off but cannot figure how.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be disabled in iOS 12 or earlier. In iPadOS 13, the magnifying glass has been removed.